# React: function comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, react-hooks

**Summary**

I have the following function inside of a functional component which keeps coming back undefined.  All of the data inside the function, tableData and subtractedStats are defined and accurate.

This is probably just a small JavaScript I'm making so your help would be greatly appreciated!

***Code***

This is a functional component below:

```
const TableComponent = ({ tableData }) => {
  formatTableData = () => {
    console.log("inside sumDataFormat", tableData);
    return tableData.forEach(competitor => {
      let subtractedStats = [];
      console.log("competitor in", competitor);
      for (const i in competitor.startingLifeTimeStats) {
        if (competitor.startingLifeTimeStats[i]) {
          competitor.stats
            ? (subtractedStats[i] =
                competitor.stats[i] - competitor.startingLifeTimeStats[i])
            : (subtractedStats[i] = 0);
        }
      }
      console.log("subtractedStats", subtractedStats);
      return subtractedStats;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("formatTableData", formatTableData());
  });
}
```

**Edit:**

Can someone help me to what's wrong in this code (how to solve this?) and could briefly explain a **functional component**

Answer (score 3):

The `forEach` function doesn't not return anything, it simply iterates over your array, giving you an `undefined`, the `map` function could be what you were looking for :

```
  formatTableData = () => {
    console.log("inside sumDataFormat", tableData);
    return tableData.map(competitor => { // This returns another array where every element is converted by what's returned in the predicate
```

Answer (score 1):

**Functional Component** are the most basic kind of React component, defined by the component's (unchanging) props.

**Functional Component** needs return some ***JSX code (UI)*** (can be *null* too).
Here's an example of most basic Functional Component

```
const App = () => {
  const greeting = 'Hello Function Component!';
  return <Headline value={greeting} />;
};
const Headline = ({ value }) => {
  return <h1>{value}</h1>;
};
export default App;
```

---

**Solution Code**

Here's the solution of the above example as a Functional Component
This is solution below uses [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to save data to component's state and also uses lifecycle methods to parse that data on componentDidMount:

```
const TableComponent = (props: ) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

    // componentDidUpdate
    useEffect(() => {
        setState(getData(props.data));
    }, []);

    // getData() - Parser for data coming inside the functional Component
    const getData = (tableData) => {
        return tableData.map(competitor => {
            return competitor.startingLifeTimeStats.map((item, index) => {
                return item && competitor.stats ? competitor.stats[index]-item : 0;
            })
        })
    };

    // UI (JSX)
    return (
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(state)}</Text>
    );
}
export default TableComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with map sample code as below.

```
render() {
return (<div>
{this.state.people.map((person, index) => (
<p>Hello, {person.name} from {person.country}!</p>
))}
</div>);
}
```